# Solving the double exponential equation $\frac{\log(4)}{x^{x^2-6}}=2$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I'm trying to solve the following double exponential equation by making use of the definition of a log

$$\frac{\log(4)}{x^{x^2-6}}=2$$

but I can't get any further than

\begin{alignat}{2}
\iff &&\log(4) &=  2x^{x^2-6}\\
\iff &&2\log(2) &=  2x^{x^2-6}\\
\iff &&\log(2) &=  x^{x^2-6}\\
\iff &&2 &=  10^{x^{x^2-6}}\\
\iff &&2 &=  10^{x^3-6x}\\
\end{alignat}

Any hints or tips to get closer to the real solutions?

Edit: the base of the logarithm is 10.

Comment: What's the base of the logarithm?

Comment: @peter.petrov based on their work it appears to be base $10$.

Comment: your last line is not correct

Comment: Notice that $\log(4)$ is just a number, so you really have an equation of the form $x^{x^2-6} = c$, which doesn't likely have a nice solution.